# How to pass on object created in function?

Tags: angular, components

```
  login() {
this.dbService.createRemoteDB();
this.dbService.createLocalDB();
let user;
this.userService
  .getUserFromRemoteDb()
  .then((userDoc: any) => {
    // Need to pass user to the next component
    user = userDoc;

    return this.syncService.getSyncDoc(user._id);
  })
  .then((syncDoc: any) => {
    return this.syncService.downloadData(user, syncDoc);
  });
```

}

My question is how can I pass "user" on to a different component? So I don't have to get the user from the database again.

Comment: Thats local scope, its not available outside the function.  There is no way to make local scopes available outside their scope.  Think about using an user class, and then access the variables, albeit making it public is not ideal for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to create a quick caching service with RxJS `Subject`. Note that there are better alternatives to be found. As noted, this would be the quickest way.

I'll use `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1 since it can "hold" the current values and emit immediately to future subscribers.

**cache.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CacheService {
  private user: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);  // <-- buffer 1
  public user$: Observable<any> = this.user.asObservable();
  
  cacheUser(user: any) {
    this.user.next(user);
  }
}
```

Login component

```js
constructor(private cache: CacheService) { }

login() {
  this.dbService.createRemoteDB();
  this.dbService.createLocalDB();

  this.userService.getUserFromRemoteDb()
    .then((userDoc: any) => {
      this.cache.cacheUser(userDoc);
      return this.syncService.getSyncDoc(user._id);
    })
    .then((syncDoc: any) => {
      return this.syncService.downloadData(user, syncDoc);
    });
}
```

Other component

```js
user: any;

constructor(private cache: CacheService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.cache.user$.subscribe(user => {
    // use `user` from login
  })
}
```